# Looking for tool for working with PostgreSQL DB

Tags: postgresql

Very simple question (I hope), does there exist a tool similar to phpMyAdmin when working with a MySQL DB but for PostgreSQL databases?

The reason I'm not just googling for a solution is that I am not as familiar with PostgreSQL as I am with MySQL and I was hoping that the SO community would be able to provide a tool that you have experience working with.

Thank you in advance for any responses. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a similar tool, [phppgadmin](http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/).  The layout is bit different from phpmyadmin but I've used it on a few of my web servers and the interface works very nicely and it's just as useful.

Comment: Thanks Parrots, interface isn't as important as to what the tool provides.  I'll check it out and post back on any success. :)

Comment: I wrote phppgadmin as a 'better' phpmyadmin, so it should be good for you :)

Comment: Just wanted to comment that I've been using it and it works great.  I highly recommend it as well. ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer a GUI app, this is really good:

http://www.pgadmin.org/features.php

Answer (score 2):

The [RazorSQL SQL GUI Tool](http://www.razorsql.com/) supports PostgreSQL and MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

PgManager 3 is a good one to administrative tasks ([www.pgadmin.org](http://www.pgadmin.org)) [not so sweet for development tasks as pgplsql dev). But you even can handle slony replication with this tool.
There is a commercial one, SQL Management Studio for PostgreSQL, it is a really good one, I was using it since a lot of time and it really shines in development and administrative tasks (http://sqlmanager.net/en/products).
Navicat for PostgreSQL is an easy one to use, simple administrative tool very similar to the MySQL one. ([pgsql.navicat.com](http://pgsql.navicat.com)) [commercial]
I remember there was a few one, but right now I can only remember those three.

Hope it helps to you!

Answer (score 0):

The [Tadpole DB Hub](https://github.com/hangum/TadpoleForDBTools/wiki) supoort PostgreSQL and Mysql, SQLite, MSSQL, Oracle, Mongodb... etc..